# Orthogonality between derivative and integral of a periodic signal

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, inner-products, orthogonality

I wonder if there is a way (if any) to prove that the inner product of the derivative and indefinite integral of any periodic signal (with period $2\pi$) from $0$ to $2\pi$ is zero, i.e., they are always orthogonal.
I tried a simple case and found that this is not always possible. For example,  for a signal
$v(t)=\cos t + \cos 2t$, we can derivate and integrate

$$\frac{d v(t)}{dt}=-\sin t - 2\sin 2t\\
\int{v(t)}=\sin t + \frac{1}{2}\sin 2t$$

so we can perform the inner product as

$$\int_0^{2\pi}{(-\sin t - 2\sin 2t)(\sin t + \frac{1}{2}\sin 2t)\neq0}$$

So they are not orthogonal!! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This "would be" orthogonality property would mean in particular the $\int_0^{2 \pi} f . f" = 0 \iff  -\int_0^{2 \pi} (f')^2=0$ for a function such that $f(0)=f(2 \pi)=0$... !

Comment: thank you for your comment.